# How to change the target element of a dropped file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I'm adding drag and drop support on a website. I have a div where you can drop files and they are uploaded but if you don't drop the file inside that specific div, the file is loaded into the browser (the default behavior)
So, the question:
Is there any way to drop the file(s) in any part of the page and send/trigger the same event to that specific div which does the file uploading?

I have a react component which handles the file uploading when you drop anything into a div, so, I was thinking on something like this code for avoiding drag and drop in the page, but instead of avoid, just send the event to another element, let's say a `<div id="dropzone"></div>`

```
window.addEventListener("dragover",function(e){
  e = e || event;
  e.preventDefault();
},false);
window.addEventListener("drop",function(e){
  e = e || event;
  e.preventDefault();
},false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach `drop` event to `<body>` element, call function which processes files with `event.dataTransfer.files`, and possibly `event`, as parameter.

Comment: I updated the question, sadly I don't have a simple javascript function to do it, all the logic is in a dropzone component, that's why i'm trying to find a way to trigger the drop into another div...otherwise, I may have to rethink the html structure due to the dropping area is very small

Comment: @Polak Not certain what you mean? Have not tried `reactjs`. Why cannot you call function which processes files within `drop` event?